# Random Restarts with "Sleep Wake Failure" error on Mavericks

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-nap

When I leave my Mavericks OS X MacBookPro idle for a while, very often it will crash and reboot by itself. After reboot, the Problem Report dialog will show up, telling that "Sleep Wake Failure experienced a problem". The problem report is not showing a crash — only powerstats from running programs. Here's the beginning of the report:

```
Date/Time:       2014-01-25 03:40:41 +0100
OS Version:      10.9.1 (Build 13B3116)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  18

Event:           Sleep Wake Failure
Steps:           50

Hardware model:  MacBookPro11,1
Active cpus:     4


Powerstats for:  [...]
```

This problem is described in various discussion forums, but I was unable to find it here. Simply googling for "sleep wakeup failure" (even without quotes) will turn up tons of relevant and unanswered threads; the same query here returns no relevant result. Those threads also include complete logs, hardware descriptions, and so on; I've excluded informations which seems unrelated (for instance, this seems to happen irrespective of the particular hardware).

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5508018?start=0&tstart=0

I have a workaround and I will post it as a self-answer, but I would like something better — a statement that Apple is investigating would make me much happier.

Another relevant error message I got is, in the Console, "Restarting to collect Sleep wake debug logs" (which seems to come from IOKit within the kernel, [see this source file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/iokit/Kernel/IOPMrootDomain.cpp)). For the same crash as above, we see that the computer wakes up on an alarm after two hours without any logs, does little for 5-6 minutes (probably trying to wake up), and then after six minutes times out and reboots.

```
Jan 25 01:34:52 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent gpu-internal-plimit-notification last value 0 (rounded time weighted average 0)
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: RTC: Maintenance 2014/1/25 02:34:49, sleep 2014/1/25 00:34:53
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::wakeEventHandlerThread
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent gpu-internal-single-slice-plimit-notification last value 0 (rounded time weighted average 0)
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent gpu-internal-plimit-notification last value 0 (rounded time weighted average 0)
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHI::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 60884 us
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 1 milliseconds
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: TBT W (2): 0x0040 [x]
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8022d1fe00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff8022d1fe00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x0c00 ****
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: ARPT: 58329.783703: si_survive_perst_war: bar0win before 18003000, bar0win after 18001000
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: ARPT: 58329.786957: pcicore_pci_pmeclr PMECSR : 0x4008
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: ARPT: 58329.786966: pcicore_pmestatclr PMECSR : 0x4008
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: ARPT: 58329.787066: pcicore_pci_pmeclr PMECSR : 0x4008
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet.local hidd[193]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 74:31:70:30:57:96
Jan 25 03:34:49 BlueVelvet.local airportd[209]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “EasyBox-305722”. Bailing on auto-join.
Jan 25 03:34:52 BlueVelvet.local Emacs-10.7[11343]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2b2826d2
Jan 25 03:34:54 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jan 25 03:34:54 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
Jan 25 03:35:27 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x0c00 ****
Jan 25 03:36:21 BlueVelvet.local WindowServer[271]: _CGXHWCaptureWindowList: No capable active display found.
Jan 25 03:37:01 BlueVelvet.local WindowServer[271]: _CGXHWCaptureWindowList: No capable active display found.
Jan 25 03:37:31 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jan 25 03:39:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Restarting to collect Sleep wake debug logs
Jan 25 03:39:49 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000310
Jan 25 03:40:03 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Resume -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x0c00 ****
Jan 25 03:40:04 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::message - kIOUSBMessagePortHasBeenReset.
Jan 25 03:40:05 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jan 25 03:40:05 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
Jan 25 03:40:05 BlueVelvet.local hidd[193]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion - Command/Response TIMED OUT and ( kRequestStateMatch == fCodecRequest->state = 2 ), fCodecRequest->command->codec: 0xffffff8023dc7f00, fCodecRequest->command->verb: 0x270503, fPoweredDown: 1
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAController at line 5527
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in IOHDACodecDevice at line 144
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget_10134208 at line 741
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDANode at line 343
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget at line 3414
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAFunctionGroup at line 919
Jan 25 03:40:06 BlueVelvet.local Emacs-10.7[11343]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2b2826d2
Jan 25 03:40:07 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion - Command/Response TIMED OUT and ( kRequestStateMatch == fCodecRequest->state = 2 ), fCodecRequest->command->codec: 0xffffff8023dc7f00, fCodecRequest->command->verb: 0x370503, fPoweredDown: 1
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAController at line 5527
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in IOHDACodecDevice at line 144
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget_10134208 at line 741
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDANode at line 343
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget at line 3414
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAFunctionGroup at line 919
Jan 25 03:40:07 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Restart still waiting on AppleHDADriver
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion - Command/Response TIMED OUT and ( kRequestStateMatch == fCodecRequest->state = 2 ), fCodecRequest->command->codec: 0xffffff8023dc7f00, fCodecRequest->command->verb: 0x470503, fPoweredDown: 1
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAController at line 5527
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in IOHDACodecDevice at line 144
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget_10134208 at line 741
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDANode at line 343
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget at line 3414
Jan 25 03:40:08 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAFunctionGroup at line 919
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion - Command/Response TIMED OUT and ( kRequestStateMatch == fCodecRequest->state = 2 ), fCodecRequest->command->codec: 0xffffff8023dc7f00, fCodecRequest->command->verb: 0x570503, fPoweredDown: 1
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAController at line 5527
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in IOHDACodecDevice at line 144
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget_10134208 at line 741
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDANode at line 343
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget at line 3414
Jan 25 03:40:09 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAFunctionGroup at line 919
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion - Command/Response TIMED OUT and ( kRequestStateMatch == fCodecRequest->state = 2 ), fCodecRequest->command->codec: 0xffffff8023dc7f00, fCodecRequest->command->verb: 0x670503, fPoweredDown: 1
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAController at line 5527
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in IOHDACodecDevice at line 144
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget_10134208 at line 741
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDANode at line 343
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget at line 3414
Jan 25 03:40:10 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAFunctionGroup at line 919
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion - Command/Response TIMED OUT and ( kRequestStateMatch == fCodecRequest->state = 2 ), fCodecRequest->command->codec: 0xffffff8023dc7f00, fCodecRequest->command->verb: 0x770503, fPoweredDown: 1
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAController at line 5527
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in IOHDACodecDevice at line 144
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget_10134208 at line 741
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDANode at line 343
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAWidget at line 3414
Jan 25 03:40:11 BlueVelvet kernel[0]: Sound assertion in AppleHDAFunctionGroup at line 919
Jan 25 03:40:28 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1390617628 0
[... rebooting logs, omitted]
Jan 25 03:40:41 BlueVelvet.local spindump[497]: Saved diag report for Sleep Wake Failure version ??? to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Sleep Wake Failure_2014-01-25-034041_BlueVelvet.diag
```

Comment: Apple would investigate this specific instance if you [file a bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) detailing the findings. When I report similar, sometimes I even get a response that it's a hardware problem and to seek service if that's the cause instead of software. There's good detail here and you might get a response although there's never a guarantee any one bug ever gets a response as many do not in practice.

Comment: I've had very similar problems with my Mac Pro (trashcan style) when I leave a G-Drive attached to the thunderbolt port. Is there anything new on this issue?

Comment: I have no news unfortunately.
However, your issue is more specific: in your case, it's a specific device to be at fault. So if you file a bug report (which I didn't yet), you'd have more chances of getting this fixed. Maybe you could talk to support of the G-Drive producers: but I guess it uses standard Thunderbolt drivers, not a driver written by this company, so I guess they can at most talk to Apple.

(But FYI, yours should be a comment to the question, not an answer).

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nothing new — the problem doesn't show up currently, either because of the workarounds mentioned below that I keep using, or because Yosemite fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

The problem seems to be that automatic wakeups from the sleep state fail, possibly because of driver-related problems*. My workaround is to simply disable automatic wakeups — and even automatic sleep. Since for me the problem only happens when leaving my computer plugged in and idle for a long time, I can disable automatic sleep only when the power adapter is connected, without reducing autonomy.

However, this will increase power consumption and reduce idle time — so you might

To apply this workaround:

- go to *System Preferences* -> *Energy Saver* -> *Power Adapter* tab.
- check the box "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off"
- uncheck the boxes "Wake for network access" and "Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter" (I also have disabled Power Nap disabled when on battery, in the *Battery* tab, but I'm not sure this was required).

*Therefore, some users only reproduce the problem when certain peripherals are plugged in.  But for one user it might be Bluetooth, for another one some USB hard disk, and so on — there's no easy to recognize pattern, which might mean the problem is due to whatever driver happens to have an apparently rather common driver bug.

Update: my laptop is a Retina MBP Late 2013, and I am not sure how much this generalizes to other laptop (see comments).

Comment: Hi, which MBP do you have? Mine is Mid 2010 and probably for this reason I don't have some of the options you mention. Here is how my power adapter tab looks like: http://imgur.com/GFrM2SZ

Comment: Yeah I've had a 13" Retinal MBP Late 2013 since they were released last year, and this just started happening to me about a week ago. It happens just about every morning after the computer has been asleep all night, but not during short sleep periods of a few minutes or an hour during the day.

Comment: I tried your suggested workaround yesterday, and today for the first time in about a week my computer didn't crash overnight. Thanks!

Comment: Gah - my computer crashed again this morning. Guess this isn't working afterall. :-( Although, looking at Console again at least the error message was different this time. Actually there doesnt' appear to be an error message exactly. Before it was `com.apple.sleep.failure` and now it's just a [hibernate log, and then a boot log](https://gist.github.com/jglovier/7d7375b50d135e4b03d4) immediately after.

Comment: So this time I tried "restore defaults" on both energy tabs (battery and adapter) and I haven't had an issue for two days. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 11):

Check with `pmset -g` for the hibernatemode setting. On my mac mini it was on `3` which is not appropriate for desktops. By changing it to 0, the issue went away. Read the excellent man page for further reference and instructions.

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode  0
```

Comment: That's interesting, but it can lose data if there's a power loss. Meanwhile, you get an upvote at least for teaching me about pmset.

Comment: Have this problem with hibernatemode set to 0.