# MacBook Pro Early 2015: Sleep Wake Failure

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Ever since I upgraded from my old MacBook Air 2012 to a brand new MacBook Pro I feel really disappointed with how my computer works.

It used to occasionally freeze, overall work more slowly (!), and the thing that is making me frustrated most of all: **Sleep Wake Failure**.

I tried to copy the log from console here but the text is too long.

Here is a screen shot of a console. I will try to insert anything that is needed here.

[image: console]

Comment: Are you able to get to an Apple Store and see an Apple Genius? Given the recent age of the computer, they should be able to help.

Comment: Take a look at [New rMBP sleep/wake failure crashes](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5500276). Sadly it looks like you are not alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119423/random-restarts-with-sleep-wake-failure-error-on-mavericks

Comment: Insufficient information to help you. Regardless how long the log is paste it on one of the places like dropbox. Include the log from the Console all messages from the point "wake reason".. Sorry, with the limited information you provided one can not even begin to analyze.

Comment: Start with providing us your system profile using the http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck In most cases it is some 3d party app responsible, since Apple does sufficient testing to have discovered fundamental problem like Sleep/Wake.

Answer (score 1):

The next time you have an issue, run [sysdiagnose](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99074/5472) by pressing the key chord for it or manually from terminal and then open a support ticket with Apple. Much of the diagnostic information in console.app requires one of two things to be useful:

- Access to Apple's source code and internal support documents
- Access to a large volume of logs from dozens (or ideally hundreds or more) of Macs to use a tool like splunk to collect and analyze various logs to identify patterns of error messages to trace back issues like this to root causes.

In the mean time, use old-fashioned pen and paper to make a note of the wall clock time when the Mac is slow and look at Activity Monitor / `top` and perhaps collect one sysdiagnose each time you notice the Mac being slow. Once you have 10 incidents, you might have enough data to know what processes are making your experience poor and determine if your slowness is related to:

- CPU constraints or [overcommitment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154624/mac-becomes-slow-and-unresponsive-when-opening-complex-pdf)
- [Memory pressure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107126/)
- [Storage issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115909/mac-os-x-mavericks-freezes-stops-responding-when-running-out-of-memory)
- Network dependancies

A good place to start on that monitoring is using `top` or `vm_stat` to run when before you notice the slowness and then review for data once you notice that the Mac has actually slowed down.

[OS X: Memory usage freaking me out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175620/os-x-memory-usage-freaking-me-out)

I would also write down what you wanted to do and what other apps were running when you notice slow downs. This will come in handy to identify if you can simply adjust the workload or need to make other changes to achieve better performance.